# temporary memory allocated for BLOB and CLOB

Tags: oracle

What I want to do is to say I have one package in that 2 and procedure and 2 function below

look like ..

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY xml_zip_pkg AS

PROCEDURE ZIP(src IN CLOB, dst IN OUT BLOB)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'com.oracle.ZipXml.zip(oracle.sql.CLOB, oracle.sql.BLOB[])';

PROCEDURE UNZIP(src IN BLOB, dst IN OUT CLOB)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'com.oracle.UnzipXml.unzipClob(oracle.sql.BLOB, oracle.sql.CLOB[])';

FUNCTION ZIP(src IN clob) RETURN blob
IS
 lvResult blob;
BEGIN
 IF src is not null THEN
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(lvResult, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
  xml_zip_pkg.ZIP(src, lvResult);
 END IF;
 RETURN lvResult;
END ZIP;

FUNCTION UNZIP(src IN blob) RETURN clob
IS
 lvResult clob;
BEGIN
 IF src is not null THEN
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(lvResult, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
  xml_zip_pkg.UNZIP(src, lvResult);
 END IF;
 RETURN lvResult;
END UNZIP;
END;
```

Output :-

`select XML_ZIP_PKG.UNZIP(XML_ZIP_PKG.ZIP('abc xyz welcome to capa town') ) from dual;`

`abc xyz welcome to capa town`

If using the `DBMS_LOB. FREETEMPORARY (lvResult);` in function, it not `RETURN` the value

`select XML_ZIP_PKG.UNZIP(XML_ZIP_PKG.ZIP('abc xyz welcome to capa town') ) from dual;`

null value

Please let me know how close to the memory issue for this package.

Comment: Why do you think you have a memory issue - are you actually seeing a problem, or just assuming this will cause one?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear if you actually have a memory issue at the moment. [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_creating.htm#ADLOB45639):

> The temporary LOB instance exists in your application until it goes out of scope, your session terminates, or you explicitly free the instance. Freeing a temporary LOB instance is recommended to free system resources.

Your function is returning the temporary LOB, so it's still in-scope to the caller. In this case the caller is your SQL query. The temporary LOB will be freed when the query completes, as it will then go out of scope. You don't need to, and can't, free it before you return it. You will only have a memory issue if you're calling your function(s) for multiple values or multiple rows at a time; the temporary LOBs from the various calls may all be in scope at the same time and could collectively use more memory than you want. As a single call it isn't really an issue though.

You can see this by running this query before and after your function call:

```
select * from v$temporary_lobs where sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID');
```

In SQL*Plus that shows `cache_lobs` as zero both before after after. In SQL Developer though it shows `cache_lobs` incrementing, which I wasn't expecting, which might be a JDBC issue. They are still freed when the session ends, but they persist until then, apparently.

Calling the function from an anonymous PL/SQL block still frees it automatically, in both SQL*Plus and SQL Developer (which I suppose makes sense as JDBC never sees the actual CLOB):

```
declare
  tmp clob;
begin
  tmp := XML_ZIP_PKG.UNZIP(XML_ZIP_PKG.ZIP('abc xyz welcome to capa town') );
end;
/
```

You can also add `DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(tmp);` within the block to free it explicitly if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks anlex but alex I have modified the script in function UNZIP using colse and freetemporary my question is should i use the before  return value or after return value. Script as below for modifying...  FUNCTION UNZIP(src IN blob) RETURN clob
IS
lvResult clob;
BEGIN
IF src is not null THEN
DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(lvResult, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
xml_zip_pkg.UNZIP(src, lvResult);
END IF;
RETURN lvResult;
-----------Close the lod session ---------
dbms_lob.close(lvResult);
dbms_lob.freetemporary(lvResult);
END UNZIP;

Comment: @user3098484 - if you free/close before returning then the LOB has gone and you have nothing to return, as you showed in the question. If you free/close after the return - well, the code will never be reached, execution of the function stops when it hits the return. You cannot return a LOB and free it in the same function.

Comment: then i want to know how to close the lob in memory.

Comment: @user3098484 - why do you think you need to explicitly close anything? You haven't said why you think this is actually a problem. If you're using the LOBs in PL/SQL rather than plain SQL then you can close them as I showed in an anonymous block. If you're using them in SQL then it doesn't seem to be an issue, except maybe over JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

Where is a problem? returned though the procedure or function blob allocator will be released after rollback/commit/disconnect.