# Do I need to deallocate a clob variable in Oracle PL/SQL function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

I had used a clob variable for creating some large XML in PL/SQL function. The function returns this CLOB variable.
Will this cause any performance degradation or memory issue?

Sample Code:

```
FUNCTION ABC
   RETURN CLOB
IS
   resultxml   CLOB;
BEGIN
   resultxml := TO_CLOB (' ');

   DBMS_LOB.writeappend (resultxml,
                         LENGTH ('---Some large data-'),
                         '---Some large data-');

   RETURN resultxml;
END;
```

Am not facing any issue right now, but want to check out whether it could create mem. issues.

Comment: You can't free it within the function since you want to return it (which was a problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23649160/266304). The caller can free it (as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23548988/266304)); but it will be freed automatically once it's out of scope. Are you actually experiencing a problem or just asking speculatively?

Comment: Thanks Alex . Am not facing any issue right now , but want to check out whether it create some problem. seems your links are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### Here, don't do it

In your specific case, you must not free the `CLOB` with `DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(resultxml)`, since it would cause issue like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23649160/266304).

### Not mandatory

Oracle shall free it automatically once it's out of scope. [Oracle says it so:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_creating.htm)

> The temporary LOB instance exists in your application until it goes out of scope, your session terminates, or you explicitly free the instance.

### It's recommended

> Freeing a temporary LOB instance is recommended to free system resources.